# runtime error for c++ code (based on pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting a runtime error for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct a
{
    int i;
}*b;

int main() {
   b->i = 1;
   a* c = new a(*b);
   cout << c->i; 
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone give me the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `i` member of an uninitialized pointer.

You need to allocate memory for `b`:

```
b = new a();
b->i = 1;
a* c= new a(*b);
cout << c->i;
delete b;
delete c;
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/935979972d135688)